# Using Unity TImeline to create a game tutorial

Tags: unity-game-engine, timeline

I have a question want to ask about `Unity Timeline`.
My game will show a tutorial screen with multiple steps to guide the user how to play my game.
Problem is I want to pause the `Timeline` when one step is finished (finished playing sound and text was shown). Please give me some advice to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a good approach would be to make each step a separate timeline. That way if you want to change the order or tweak some steps its a lot easier.

Something else to consider is setting your director to manual update mode.I think its PlayableDirector.timeUpdateMode. The you can call evaluate(deltatime) on it. That way you have all the control. You can pause/stop the update when you want that way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try.